# Making 2nd level pure CSS dropdown menu to appear when hovering over 1st level menu item

Tags: css

I have created a navigation bar using pure CSS coding and no JavaScript coding at all. But I have one problem in the browser interface of it. I want to make my 2nd level MENU ITEMS appear when I hover with my mouse over the 1 st level menu item ( AKA sub menu of MAIN MENU item). But as per the current situation, when I hover over the main menu item called "Online Services", I can see the 1st level menu item, "Communication" and the corresponding 2nd level menu item list, called "Email","Instant Messaging" and "Social Networking" altogether at once!

So as I said above, I want to hide the 2nd level menu items when the main menu item, "Online Services" is hovered. BUT, I want to make it ONLY appear, when the 1st level menu item, "Communication" is hovered as per the mentioned current situation above.

Here is my HTML code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 #navMenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navMenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
}
#navMenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #222;
}
#navMenu ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 40px;
}
#navMenu ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>The Information Age</title>

  <link href="css/dropDown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Online Services</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Communication</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Email</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Instant Messaging</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Social Networking</a>
                </li>


              </ul>
              <!--inner 2nd UL-->

              <li><a href="#">Online Education</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Online Entertainment</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Web Storage</a>
              </li>





            </li>
            <!--inner LI-->
          </ul>
          <!--end inner UL-->




        </li>
        <!--end main LI-->
      </ul>
      <!--end main UL-->


    </div>
    <!--end navMenu-->
  </div>
  <!--end wrapper div-->






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is "2rd"?

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried

Comment: Hello @RobynOverstreet , the CSS and HTML code are mentioned above !

Comment: Hi @connexo , please refer to the newest changes/edit to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the direct descendant on hover:

```
#navMenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

that way it won't select unless it is a direct child, rather than all child elements.

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector, regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM. ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

A full demo can be seen below:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 #navMenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navMenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
}
#navMenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #222;
}
#navMenu ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 40px;
}
#navMenu ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>The Information Age</title>

  <link href="css/dropDown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Online Services</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Communication</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Email</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Instant Messaging</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Social Networking</a>
                </li>


              </ul>
              <!--inner 2nd UL-->

              <li><a href="#">Online Education</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Online Entertainment</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">E-Commerce</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Web Storage</a>
              </li>





            </li>
            <!--inner LI-->
          </ul>
          <!--end inner UL-->




        </li>
        <!--end main LI-->
      </ul>
      <!--end main UL-->


    </div>
    <!--end navMenu-->
  </div>
  <!--end wrapper div-->






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello @jbutler483 . Thank you so much for the help provided! I ran the code snippet sent by you and copied the code to my css file and it worked like a charm! Never thought i will be able to get my menus right.. Anyway, thanks alot because you rock!

Comment: @RazmanF if this worked for you, and you are happy to accept it as the answer to your question, please feel free to click on the checkmark to the left of my answer to accept it ;)